# How to make Unity 3d random range gameobject destroy?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi unity random range destroy want make but how make i dont know

instance: random.range (1,3) // 1 with 3 range destroy to make gameobject want

!To explain in more detail, as can be seen in the picture, there are 9 gameobjects, I want them to destroy them randomly when I click on any of them, for example between 1 and 3.

image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwYYh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hae them in a data structure, for example a `List` so that they can be selected and destroyed randomly.

```
objPool = new List<GameObject>();  
//fill the list
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
{
    objPool.Add(yourCubeReference);  
}
```

Then you can just obtain a random index, and destroy one random item like this

```
int index = Random.Range(0, 9);//or int index = Random.Range(0, 3); if you wish
GameObject.Destroy(objPool[index];) 
objPool.RemoveAt(index)//keep your list updated
```

Then if you wish te keep on destroying random objects remember that you have one element less to choose from, so possible max index needs to be -1, so in the next iteration you you need `int index = Random.Range(0, 8);`. 8 instead of 9.

You can keep this updated taking the elements of the list in the code itslef `int index = Random.Range(0, objPool.Count -1);` as long as you keep the list updated.